# How to pass an object as an argument in order to store data to a database?

Tags: android, sqlite, fragment

I am relatively new to Android and I'm a little bit stuck as fighting my way through databases, so any guidelines are much appreciated! Here it goes~

```
    //Random Fragment that inserts data to the databaase
    mWorkoutData = new WorkoutData();
    mDBTools = new DBTools(getActivity());

    HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap =  new HashMap<String, String>();

    queryValuesMap.put("comments", mWorkoutData.getComments());

    mDBTools.insertWorkoutData(queryValuesMap);
```

The WorkoutData is the model class, however it does not manage to insert any data to the database while in case I pass an Edittext for example as an argument everything is fine!

Any guidelines or insights on how to solve this would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

DBTools

```
    public void insertWorkoutData(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();



    values.put("comments", queryValues.get("comments"));


    db.insert("workouts", null, values);

    db.close();
}
```

This is the respective method from DBTools to insert this specific data, I believe that the DBTools class is working properly, since I am able to see data on my listview in case I pass something like

```
 queryValuesMap.put("comments", EditText.getText().toString());
```

instead of

```
queryValuesMap.put("comments", mWorkoutData.getComments());
```

which was described above.

**EDIT2**

```
   //Random Fragment number 2 prior to random Fragment of the code above
   mWorkoutData.setComments(mTrainingEditText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: `DBTools` is...your `SQLiteOpenHelper`? Without the code for `DBTools` there's not much I can help you with.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer,  I edited my question! (Yes, DBTools is my SQLiteOpenHelper class)

Comment: The gist of the answer below is "what does `mWorkoutData.getComments()` return?". Set a breakpoint on that line and hit `Alt + F8` to evaluate that expression and make sure it's what you think, it is. There's no reason in principal that there should discriminate one `String` from another.

Answer (score 0):

You constructed a `workoutData` object and then called `getComments` on it, but I would assume at that point that comments is null. You need to set value for comments before you try to read it back out.

Comment: Hmmm, Thanks for your answer I did set a value. mWorkoutData.setComments(mTrainingEditText.getText().toString()); Is this supposed to be at a specific place maybe, outside of onCreateView ? Additionally, this happens prior to the getComments call! Thanks in advance!

Comment: That line of code is not in the code sample you pasted above

Comment: Thanks! I apologize edited my question, this code sample exists in another fragment prior to the getComments call. I suspect that this is a rookie mistake. I am grateful for any insights~

Comment: But in the first code block you create a NEW workoutdata object right before calling getComments. Perhaps you can just remove that line.

Comment: I think I did not describe as well as I could, the setComments takes place in a totally different fragment prior to the getComments fragment.

Comment: In that case you need to be able to pass data between the fragments. Since you are creating a new workout data it is empty. As quick test you can try making the comments field static in the workoutdata class.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I figured my mistake with your help (which is embarrassing), have a great day sir!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but a suggestion I want to make to you that is longer than I can do in comments.

Whenever you're working with databases, you should use a contract class to store the constants. This will make your code easier to write and less prone to errors from typos. This might even be your problem. But basically you just make a class something like

```
public class WorkoutDatabaseContract {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "fitness"

    public static final String TABLE_WORKOUTS = "workouts"
    ...
    public static final String FIELD_COMMENTS = "comments"
    ...
}
```

Then your calls to your database look like

```
values.put(WorkoutDatabaseContract.FIELD_COMMENTS, queryValues.get(WorkoutDatabaseContract.FIELD_COMMENTS));
-or-
queryValuesMap.put(WorkoutDatabaseContract.FIELD_COMMENTS, workoutData.getComments);
```

It's less compact, but you do less typing because it Idea will auto complete for you, and you don't have to rely on your typing ability to get the field right everywhere. Plus if you ever change anything, you only have to change it in one place.

Comment: Thank you seiterm for your suggestions, I am aware of this way and I couldn't agree more! I think I will start working towards with this scheme once i get the time~ Thanks, have a nice day!